# I have problem with Unity tile pallette can someone help me?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, tiles, tile

I'd like to use Unity **tiles** and tilesmap with **[image: tile palette]**... but I cant **find** it!!!

Comment: Install it with the Package Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-find-unity-tilemap-palette.507962/)

> **Unity Technologies:**
>
> For 2019.2 and above, if you created a new Unity project, you will need to add the `2D Tilemap Editor` package from the Unity `Package Manager` (under Window → Package Manager) to your project to be able to create Tiles and access the `Tile Palette`.
>
> If you created a new Unity project with the 2D template, the package will be added for you automatically.
>
> If you upgraded from a previous Unity version, the package will be automatically added as well.

---

For installing a package follow the [Installing packages from the registry 
- Manuall](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-install.html) which in short goes:

1. Open the [Package Manager Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html) via <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Package Manager</kbd>
2. set the [Filter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-filter.html) to `All Packages`
3. search for the [Tilemap 2D Editor Package](http://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.tilemap@1.0/manual/index.html)
4. Hit <kbd>Install</kbd>

After doing this the options you are looking for should be under `Window` → `2D` → `Tile Palette` and `Create` → `2D Object` → `TileMap`